# Android List view or any other with switch option

Tags: android, listview, switch-statement

[image: They Layout]

I want to make the above layout from code behind. It could be a listview with switch or any other.
Can someone give me some idea about how to proceed?

I am open to any layout. Relative layout will work fine with me or any other for that matter. I know how to populate list view form code behind or switch in the right. but i don't know how to combine them and produce it form code behind

Comment: Open Eclipse (or some other editor), decide on a `Layout` you would like to try, try it, come back here with a specific question when you are stuck

Comment: you can create a cutsom listView with a textView and two buttons. here's a guide which you can adapt to your need http://looksok.wordpress.com/tag/listview-item-with-button/ .

Comment: @codeMagic: I am open to any layout. Relative layout will work fine with me or any other for that matter. I know how to populate list view form code behind or switch in the right. but i don't know how to combine them and produce it form code behind.

Comment: See, that's a little clearer question. You can use a custom `ListView`, `extend ListActivity` and inflate your custom layout in `getView()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will produce your `switch` and `TextView` for each row in your `adapter`

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, parent, false);  // create your_layout.xml with the layout you want
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.label = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.itemTV);
            holder.switch = get your switch here

            rowView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }
```

If you don't already know about using `ViewHolder` you will want to read the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html). You also should watch [Google I/O TurboCharge Your UI](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html). If this isn't what you are talking about then let me know